# Longest Palindrome: What could be slowing down my DP solution?

Tags: python, dynamic-programming, palindrome

Here is my solution to the following leetcode problem: https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-palindromic-substring/

Find the longest palindromic substring (a palindrome is a string that is the same forwards and backwards).

My solution somehow passes all their test cases but runs over the time limit. I've implemented a DP based solution and cant figure out what might be taking extra time.

```py
class Solution:
    def longestPalindrome(self, s: str) -> str:
        table = [[True] for i in range(len(s))]
        best = (0,1)
        for i in range(len(s) - 1):
          for j in range(0, len(s) - i -1):
            size = i + 1
            shift = j
            diag = table[j + 1][i-1]
            eq = s[shift] ==  s[shift + size]
            table[j].append(diag and eq)
            if diag and eq: best = (shift,  shift + size + 1)
        return s[best[0]:best[1]]
```

Comment: There's no subtle detail you're missing - your algorithm is just slow, for the fairly simple reason that those loops take quadratic time. You need a better algorithm.

Comment: I didnt know this could be done faster than quadratic. I'll have to think about it more.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to approach the problem,
start by defining a window-size (like a sliding-window) and try to slice the string with that window size amount and check if it's palindrome.

Should you reach the end without any solution, just decrease your window size and start all over again until you find a palindrome.

Here is an example code:

```
class Solution:
    def longestPalindrome(self, s: str) -> str:
        window_size = len(s)
        while True:
            for i in range(0, (len(s) - window_size) + 1):
                if s[i : i + window_size] == s[i:i + window_size][::-1]:
                    return s[i : i + window_size]
            else:
                window_size -= 1
```

---

comparison of result of the snippet from the question and this answer's (respectively):

[image]

Comment: This is even slower than the algorithm in the question.

Comment: it is NOT. we are starting **from the longest substring** and go all the way to smaller!

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I've added the result comparison on my answer for you to see

Comment: "we are starting from the longest substring and go all the way to smaller" - that doesn't make it faster. It runs quickly if the longest palindromic substring takes up most of the original string, but it's extremely slow if the longest palindromic substring is short.

Comment: This is a naive O(n^3) solution. If this got accepted when the code in the question timed out, then that's a flaw in the test cases.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica this is not code-review. Op's answer wasn't getting accepted for exceeding the time limit, I provided one that works (without in-fact claiming that it was better). I don't really get what the point you're making but have it your way.

Comment: If you're *not* claiming your code is faster, then it doesn't make sense to post it as an answer on a "why is my code slow" question.